# How to maintain element version in xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, versioning

I have 3 different xsds.
xsd2 is superset of xsd1.
xsd3 is superset of xsd2.
I have all 3 different clients that may of either of the xsds.
And for each xml quest from them using their xsd, i have to generate a xml response.
i think if i maintain somewhere which element, element-property is supported in which version, then based on that list, i can chose to populate or not to populate that element using the xsd3. On server i am thinking to use xsd3. hence using the version list, i will be able to generate xmls that can be parsed by xsd1 & xsd2.
I want to maintain this element-version mapping inside the xsd itself.
how do i do that? 
i use jaxb for xml parsing on server side

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds as if the differences among versions are just in the set of elements declared, so that we can derive xsd2 from xsd3 by deleting some xs:element elements, and ditto for deriving xsd1 from xsd2.

On that assumption, the simplest way to manage an element-version mapping is to add an attribute in some non-XSD namespace to each element declaration, specifying which versions include / support that element.

```
<xs:element name="E" type="tns:T" my:versions="1"/>
<xs:element name="F" type="tns:T2" my:versions="1 2 3"/>
<xs:element name="G" type="tns:T3" my:versions="1 2"/>
<xs:element name="H" type="tns:T4" my:versions="1"/>
```

You can also use xs:annotation/xs:appinfo to manage more complex information.

Whether these give you what you need depends on the interface offered by your XSD tools, or on your ability to extract the information from the schema document and exploit it yourself without assistance from the XSD tool.